# How does the arduino serial buffer works?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I have a doubt with the buffer of the arduino serial.

When you read data from the buffer it's deleted or a pointer moves and it cannot be read again.

For example:
Is the data in the buffer deleted in this code?:

```
 while(Serial.available()>0)    {
  delay(5); 
  cadena[posicion]=Serial.read();
  posicion++;
 }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the data is read it is removed from the buffer. That's why simply reading the in buffer already frees space for new data to come.